exploded annualized returns and volatilities when period return larger than 100%?
When my monthly returns is larger than 100%, I get very weird output for annualized return and volatility as follows:
Return [%]          Annual Return [%]   Volatility (Ann.) [%]
198.149674908792    49341369.7397401    703.361571453399

the formula I used:
annual_return = (1 + total_return / 100) ^ (252/duration.days) -1 
annual_volatility = daily_volatility * sqrt(252)

total_return is the monthly returns in %.
duration.days: # days in the calculation period, usually a month
Which part did i get wrong? or there are special formula to calculate periodic returns that is larger than 100%? Thanks.

Is duration.days the days that have elapsed for monthly returns/total_return?

@KaiSqDist: edited. thanks.

I see the problem, you are compounding, not annualizing. Annualizing the returns is just multiplying the expected returns. For example, you should divide by duration.days and multiply by 252 instead of using an exponent.

@KaiSqDist, ah I see! thanks a lot!

Can you accept my answer or give me an upvote if you feel it helped? Thanks!

I see the problem, you are compounding, not annualizing. Annualizing the returns is just multiplying the expected returns. For example, you should divide by duration.days and multiply by 252 instead of using an exponent.
